# checkboxes loose his state

Tags: javafx, checkbox, tableview

I created a table with 3 columns. In middle column i have 3 checkboxes. When my window is initialize checkboxes are ticked if info from database is suitable. It works. User can unticked checkbox what changing informations in database. My problem is when I verify did checkbox are selected one time returns true, one time returns false but the checkboxes is in the same state (selected or not).

```
public CheckBox podglad2, edycja2, dodawanie2, usuwanie2, importowanie2, eksportowanie2, nadawanie2;


private static void setAccessLabelStyle2(CheckBox label, AccessLevel level, Integer value) {
    if (check(level, value)) {
        label.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        label.setSelected(false);
    }
}

private static boolean check(AccessLevel accessLevel, Integer value) {
    return (accessLevel.getBit() & value) > 0;
}


public TableCell getFunctionCell2(TableCell cell, Integer accessLevel) {
    HBox graphics = new HBox();
    graphics.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    graphics.setSpacing(7.0);

    podglad2 = new CheckBox("P");
    setAccessLabelStyle2(podglad2, AccessLevel.VIEW, accessLevel);

    dodawanie2 = new CheckBox("D");
    setAccessLabelStyle2(dodawanie2, AccessLevel.CREATE, accessLevel);

    edycja2 = new CheckBox("E");
    setAccessLabelStyle2(edycja2, AccessLevel.UPDATE, accessLevel);

}

accessLevelCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
        return new TableCell<FunctionTableModel, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    getFunctionCell2(this, item);

                    podglad2.setOnAction(e -> {
                        FunctionTableModel row = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        if (check(AccessLevel.VIEW, row.getAccessLevel())) {
                            if (podglad2.isSelected() == false) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() - AccessLevel.VIEW.getBit());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (podglad2.isSelected() == true) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() + AccessLevel.VIEW.getBit());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    dodawanie2.setOnAction(e -> {

                        FunctionTableModel row = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        if (check(AccessLevel.CREATE, row.getAccessLevel())) {
                            if (dodawanie2.isSelected() == false) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() - AccessLevel.CREATE.getBit());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (dodawanie2.isSelected() == true) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() + AccessLevel.CREATE.getBit());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    edycja2.setOnAction(e -> {
                        FunctionTableModel row = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        if (check(AccessLevel.UPDATE, row.getAccessLevel())) {
                            if (edycja2.isSelected() == false) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() - AccessLevel.UPDATE.getBit());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (edycja2.isSelected() == true) {
                                row.setAccessLevel(row.getAccessLevel() + AccessLevel.UPDATE.getBit());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

How can I solved this?

Comment: How does your cell display anything? The only modification to the `graphic`, `style` or `text` properties happen when setting `text` and `style` to the default values. Furthermore why are those `CheckBox`es ect stored in the containing class instead of the cell itself. Even if you make your code work partially by fixing the issue mentioned before, this would result in the `onAction` event handlers always referencing the `CheckBox`es from the cell that was updated last. For setting bits a flags `int` I recommend bitwise operations btw: `value |= mask`for setting and`value &= ~mask`for unsetting

Comment: You were right. Thanks for helps.